# "Convergence speed" results for the Langevin process

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, st.statistics, stochastic-processes

The Langevin process is defined by the following stochastic differential equation:

$$ \dot X = - \nabla \phi + \sqrt 2 dW_t $$

Its equilibrium distribution is the following:

$$ p_\infty (x) \propto \exp( - \phi(x) ) $$

(unless I've messed up a constant or two ^^)

Now consider the following: we initialize a particle at position $x_0$ at time $t=0$ and we look at the sequence of probability distributions describing where the particle could be at time $t$

$$  x \rightarrow p(x ; x_0, t) $$

This family respects the Fokker-Planck forward equation (and the Kolmogorov backward equation). If I'm not mistaken, (with some small additional assumptions) as $t \rightarrow \infty$, $p(x; x_0, t) \rightarrow p_\infty$.

I'm interested in further characterizations of the family of probability distributions $p(x; x_0, t)$. Can we give total variation bounds on the convergence to $p_\infty$ ? Or any other metric for that matter (I'm particularly interested in the Wasserstein-1 distance) ?

Furtheremore: intuitively, $p(x; x_0 + \epsilon, t)$ and $p(x; x_0, t)$ should be close: are there any known characterizations of that fact ?

Finally, a simple question: does the family $p(x; x_0, t)$ have a name ?

Answer (score 1):

The convergence of the *time-dependent probability distribution* $p(x;x_0,t)$ to its long-time limit was studied, also in connection to the Wasserstein distance, in [On the trend to equilibrium for the Fokker-Planck equation](http://cedricvillani.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/P01.MV-FPReview.pdf):

> We present connections between the problem of trend to equilibrium for
>   the Fokker-Planck equation of statistical physics, and several
>   inequalities from functional analysis, like logarithmic Sobolev or
>   Poincare inequalities, together with some inequalities arising in the
>   context of concentration of measures (Talagrand inequality and
>   Wasserstein distance), or in the study of Gaussian isoperimetry.

Comment: Thank you very much. This answers a lot of my questions. Would you happen to know whether the Brascamp-Lieb inequality (which extends the Poincaré inequality) can also be used to prove convergence speed results of a similar form ? It reads, for $p\propto \exp(-\phi(x))$ a log-concave probability distribution: $ var_p(S(x)) \leq E_p( S'(x)^2 / \phi ''(x)) $